# pgfplots@y@inverseveclength ->infty

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, bar-chart

I'm experiencing problems with pgfplots. The following piece of code was automatically generated by a piece of software I'm working on.

```
\documentclass {standalone}
\errorcontextlines 10000
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10} 
\pgfplotsset{single xbar legend/.style={legend image code/.code={\draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,bar width=6pt,bar shift=0pt,xbar] plot coordinates {(0.8em,0pt)};}}}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{fillbkgeleWjets}{rgb}{0.200000,0.600000,0.200000}
\definecolor{fillbkgeleZjets}{rgb}{0.600000,0.800000,0.600000}
\definecolor{fillbkgeletopttbar}{rgb}{1.000000,0.800000,0.200000}
\definecolor{fillbkgeletopsingletop}{rgb}{0.800000,0.600000,0.200000}
\definecolor{fillbkgeleDiBoson}{rgb}{0.400000,0.600000,0.800000}
\definecolor{fillsigeleSherpa}{rgb}{0.600000,0.800000,1.000000}
\definecolor{drawsigeleSherpa}{rgb}{1.000000,0.000000,0.000000}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
label,{dataele},{bkgeleWjets},{bkgeleZjets},{bkgeletopttbar},{bkgeletopsingletop},{bkgeleDiBoson},{sigeleSherpa}
{afterPresel},{0.605647},{0.265529},{0.0879903},{0.0320347},{0.0050964},{0.000518178},{0.00318414}
{mT > 40GeV w/ dphi/mjj cuts},{0.540969},{0.39966},{0.0377578},{0.0124966},{0.00496115},{0.000191084},{0.00396388}
}\datatable
\begin{axis}[
    height=3*1.5em+2*5pt,  % this line is faulty, replace the '3' with '4' have it render without problem
    enlarge y limits={abs=5pt},
    xmin=0,
    tick align=outside,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left,
    every y tick/.style={draw=none},
    xbar stacked,   
    y dir=reverse,
    scaled x ticks=false,
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    enlarge x limits=false,
    bar width=10pt,
    ytick=data,
    yticklabels from table={\datatable}{label},
]
\addplot[] table [x=dataele, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\addplot[fill=fillbkgeleWjets] table [x=bkgeleWjets, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\addplot[fill=fillbkgeleZjets] table [x=bkgeleZjets, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\addplot[fill=fillbkgeletopttbar] table [x=bkgeletopttbar, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\addplot[fill=fillbkgeletopsingletop] table [x=bkgeletopsingletop, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\addplot[fill=fillbkgeleDiBoson] table [x=bkgeleDiBoson, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\addplot[fill=fillsigeleSherpa,draw=drawsigeleSherpa] table [x=sigeleSherpa, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

It seems like the exact value of the `height` parameter is causing problems - replacing the `3` with a `4` in the code causes the rendering to be fine, while the current version produces the following error - it seems like some of the math inside pgfplots produces `infty` as a result, which then fails to classify as a number.

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   i
\pgfplots@y@inverseveclength ->i
                                nfty
\pgfplotsconvertunittocoordinate ...gth\endcsname 
                                                  \pgf@xa \edef \pgfmathresu...

\pgfplots@scaling@apply@enlargelimits@by@dimension ...
                                                  \edef \pgfplots@loc@TMPa {...

\pgfplots@initsizes ...argelimits@by@dimension {y}
                                                  \ifpgfplots@threedim \pgfp...

\pgfplots@determinedefaultvalues ...ots@initsizes 
                                                  \pgfplots@check@and@apply@...

\endpgfplots@environment@opt ...minedefaultvalues 
                                                  \pgfplots@BEGIN@cell@pictu...

\end #1->\csname end#1\endcsname 
                                 \@checkend {#1}\expandafter \endgroup \if@e...
l.44 \end{axis}
```

Interestingly, replacing the `3` with a `2` causes a different error, which makes much more sense to me:

```
! Package pgfplots Error: Error: Plot height `30.00003pt' is too small. This ca
nnot be implemented while maintaining constant size for labels. Sorry, label si
zes are only approximate. You will need to adjust your height..
```

Since the document is automatically generated, I only have limited control over the contents of the value of `height`. currently, the value is generated as follows:

`(Number of barcharts + 1 [for axis labels]) * (lineheight [user input, default 1.5em]) + 2 * margin [user input, default 5pt])`

I can change this calculation to anything sensible if neccessary, but I would like to keep it such that the user can control the size of the plot independently of the number of barcharts (because the program will spit out several such documents in each go with different numbers of barcharts which should have a consistent scaling for the same user input). If there's an option inside pgfplots that allows to do this, I'm happy to abandon the current procedure in favour of whatever works.

While I would prefer to find a solution that makes the document render successfully in all cases, I would already be happy with something that works for sensible defaults in a sensible range of barcharts (1-20).

Comment: By default, when you specify a `height` for the axis, PGFPlots assumes that a certain part of that height is required for the labels. For small `height` values, this can lead to a plot area that's too small. If you need fine control over the plot siye, you should set `scale only axis`. That way, the `height` value only refers to the plot area itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, when you specify a `height` for the axis, PGFPlots assumes that a certain part of that height is required for the labels. For small `height` values, this can lead to a plot area that's too small. If you need fine control over the plot size, you should set `scale only axis`. That way, the `height` value only refers to the plot area itself.